# iFrame keeps forcing my page to scroll to top

Tags: iframe, google-docs

I just made a page in WP which has 3 iframes inside it. One is a google Calendar, and two others are Google Docs (spreadsheets).

The google calendar works fine, but everytime I click on something in the google docs, it scrolls my whole page (not my iframe, but the page that contains the three iframes) to the top. I simply want it to not scroll, and stay in the same place, so I can edit the Google doc document on my website.

Comment: Actually, I just tried this on IE, and it is not scrolling. I am using Google Chrome, and it still scrolls. So is it something to do with my browser?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you have switched on caret browsing in FF? press F7 to toggle

Comment: I tried adding 
<script language="javascript"> 
function scrolltotop() { 
scroll(0,0); 
} 
</script>

and onload="scrolltotop() to my iframe code. But that didn't do anything.